# How to duplicate all values in a table SQL Sever 2008, with unique Identification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have a table called **table123**, with about 80 rows. It includes the columns '**ID**', '**First_Name**', '**Surname**', '**Job_Title**', '**Salary**' and '**Address**'.

I have created a new table called **table987**, which is an exact copy of **table123**. This is to not ruin **table123** with any commands.

Within **table987**, I want to duplicate all values, so that there will be 2 copies of each row. So, if I have a row with '*John*' as '**First_Name**', I want the duplicate copy of '*John*' to come right after it in the table.

However, I don't want the duplicate copy to have the same '**ID**'. Each row should have a unique '**ID**'. Essentially, there should be 2 of each record, but each should have a unique '**ID**'.

I have tried using the following script to duplicate the values, but each duplicate has the same '**ID**' as the original record:

```
INSERT INTO table987 (ID, First_Name, Surname, Job_Title, Salary, Address)
    SELECT ID, First_Name, Surname, Job_Title, Salary, Address
    FROM table123;
```

Is there a specific script I could use to sort out the duplicates in such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answer is already accepted, seeing the comments above (*"but now it's just jumbled all over the place"*), I want to add the **ORDER BY** clause to the query, which will give you the ordered data as you required in the mentioned comments above:

```
DECLARE @table123 table(ID int, First_Name varchar(100),Surname varchar(100),Job_Title varchar(100),Address varchar(100))
DECLARE @table987 table(ID int, First_Name varchar(100),Surname varchar(100),Job_Title varchar(100),Address varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @table123 
VALUES
    (1,'FName1','Surname1','JobTitle1','Address1'),
    (2,'FName2','Surname2','JobTitle2','Address2'),
    (3,'FName3','Surname3','JobTitle3','Address3'),
    (4,'FName4','Surname4','JobTitle4','Address4'),
    (5,'FName5','Surname5','JobTitle5','Address5')

INSERT INTO @table987
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM @table123
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM @table123)result ORDER BY ID

SELECT * FROM @table987;
```

**Output:**

```
--------------------------------------------------
|ID  First_Name   Surname    Job_Title   Address |
|------------------------------------------------|
|1    FName1      Surname1   JobTitle1   Address1|
|1    FName1      Surname1   JobTitle1   Address1|
|2    FName2      Surname2   JobTitle2   Address2|
|2    FName2      Surname2   JobTitle2   Address2|
|3    FName3      Surname3   JobTitle3   Address3|
|3    FName3      Surname3   JobTitle3   Address3|
|4    FName4      Surname4   JobTitle4   Address4|
|4    FName4      Surname4   JobTitle4   Address4|
|5    FName5      Surname5   JobTitle5   Address5|
|5    FName5      Surname5   JobTitle5   Address5|
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Although the previous answer is very similar, this one is more understandable

Answer (score 2):

Use **UNION ALL** and set '**ID**' as auto increment or set default value NEWID()

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.table987 
    ( First_Name ,
      Surname ,
      Job_Title ,
      Salary ,
      Address
    )
    SELECT  First_Name ,
            Surname ,
            Job_Title ,
            Salary ,
            Address
    FROM    dbo.table123
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  First_Name ,
            Surname ,
            Job_Title ,
            Salary ,
            Address
    FROM    dbo.table123
```

Comment: Is the dbo. necessary before a table name?

Comment: I've just tried this, and it's pretty much the same as the script I used, but now it's just jumbled all over the place.

Comment: No, dbo. is not necessary if we are using temporary table.

Comment: According to your question 'ID' should be unique in each row and in accepted answer doesn't show any unique value.